# Как узнать номер строки datagrid в wpf?

Tags: wpf, c#

Как узнать номер строки `datagrid` в wpf? Например, при нажатии правой кнопки мыши, чтоб выскакивало окно "строка такая-то, столбец такой-то"?
В `winforms`: `e.rows`... тут это не катит.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
int parse = dataGrid1.SelectedIndex; 
DataRowView rowView = dataGrid1.SelectedValue as DataRowView;
```

номер строки

значение строки в какой-то колонке

*например*

```
rowView[0].ToString(); // вернет значение выбранной строки в первой колонке
```

Answer (score 1):

Номер строки описал johniek_comp:

```
dataGrid1.SelectedIndex;
```

Номер столбца:

```
DataRowView dataRow = (DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedItem;
int index = datagrid1.CurrentCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
```

А вообще [избитая тема](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225568/wpf-datagrid-get-selected-cell-value)

Answer (score -1):

вот так проще всего

```
result=dg.Items.IndexOf(dg.SelectedCells[0].Item);
```

> result - int; dg - datagrid;